# Create a new Docker VM

Tags: docker

I am trying to create a new Docker VM in my OS X 10.9.5 using

```
$ docker-machine create embedded --url tcp://192.168.99.101:2376
```

but when I list the machines:

```
Macintosh:~ joanet$ docker-machine ls
NAME       ACTIVE   DRIVER   STATE   URL                         SWARM
embedded            none             tcp://192.168.99.101:2376
```

I see that the DRIVER is set to none, and I think it should be set as virtualbox, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that [`test/integration/drivers/virtualbox/pause-save-start.bats`](https://github.com/docker/machine/blob/7925bf26834ae35dbb85fe19f370db5dc9003f33/test/integration/drivers/virtualbox/pause-save-start.bats#L5) has a line like:

```
force_env DRIVER virtualbox
```

(with [force_env](https://github.com/docker/machine/blob/7925bf26834ae35dbb85fe19f370db5dc9003f33/test/integration/helpers.bash#L16-L21) checking the value of the environment variable `DRIVER`), you need indeed to set `DRIVER` to `virtualbox`.

It should be set prior to call, for instance, [`docker machine create`](https://github.com/docker/machine/blob/af08468f00f3109961d279b83c538633459c434d/test/integration/core/supported-engine-options.bats#L5-L13).

```
docker machine create -d virtualbox ...
```